# In laravel 6 sending form data in post method giving error as The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-6, laravel-form

I tried to store entire form data as post method into route in post method giving error as below

The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.

please look at the below code

web.php

```
 Route::get('/purchase/index','PurchasesController@index')->name('purchase.index');
 Route::get('/purchase/create','PurchasesController@create')->name('purchase.create');
 Route::post('/purchase/store','PurchasesController@store')->name('purchase.store');
```

create.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.nav') @section('content')

<div class="container  mt-3 border ">
    <div class="row  justify-content-center align-items-center" style="background-color:teal;color:#fff;">

        <h1> Purchase Details</h1>
    </div>
    {!!Form::open(['route'=>['purchase.store'],'id'=>'purchase_form','method'=>'POST'])!!}

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row   float-left m-3">
            {{-- {!!Form::open(['route'=>['purchase.store'],'id'=>'purchase_form','method'=>'POST'])!!} --}}

            <form>
                Date:
                <input type="date" date-format="mm-dd-yyyy" placeholder="MM-DD-YYYY" name="date" id="datePicker">

            </form>
        </div>
        <!-- <div class="col-sm-4 pull-right " style="margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:5px;">-->
        <div class="row  justify-content-center float-right m-3">

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info add-new" id="addnew"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add New</button>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container mt-3">
        <form method="POST" action=" ">
            <table class="table table-bordered" id="tb2">
                <thead class="text-center">
                    <tr class="tr-header">
                        <th>CI No</th>
                        <th>ItemName</th>
                        <th>Unit</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>SubTotal</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                    <tr>

                        <td class="clid"></td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control name" name="name" id="inputGroupSelect01">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control qty" name="qty" id="qty">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control rate" name="rate" id="rate">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control subTotal" name="subTotal" id="subTotal">
                        </td>

                        <td> <a class="delete" title="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE872;</i></a> </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

    </div>
    <div class="float-right m-3">
        {{-- {!!Form::submit('Submit');!!} --}}
        <form method="POST" action="/purchase/store">
            <button type="submit" name="edit" class="btn btn-primary ">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class=" float-right m-3">
        <h5><b>Grand Total</b></h5>
        <input type="text-box" class="grandTotal" maxlength="10" size="10">
    </div>

</div>

</div>
{!!Form::close()!!} @stop
```

PurchasesController.php

```
 public function store(Request $request)
 {
      //
        return "i have entered store";
 }
```

Comment: Your form codes are all messed up. You have three forms within another form, and the one of the forms has no action `<form method="POST" action=" ">`, so it will post to the page you're on. Fix your forms, and you'll fix your issue.

Comment: Please pass the form method post and CSRF token to post your data in controller.

Comment: You write run  command in your CMD.   php artisan route:list so you can also get 6 method to store update fetch..like..so you can also get your route from this command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use

```
<form method="POST" action="{{url(purchase/store)}}">
```

And make sure that you are not using a prefix group